# simple_query_string check if field exists

Tags: elasticsearch

How would I use simple_query_string to check if a field exists? For example, say if I had the following documents

```
PUT test_index/_doc/1
{
"user" : "test",
"message" : "a"
}

PUT test_index/_doc/2
{
"user" : "test",
"message" : "b"
}

PUT test_index/_doc/3
{
"user" : "test",
"message" : "c"
}

PUT test_index/_doc/4
{
"user" : "test"
}
```

How do I query for documents where (message = "a" OR "b") OR (message field doesn't exist). The query should return documents 1, 2 and 4. I realise this is trivial with

```
"must_not": {
  "exists": {
    "field": "message"
  }
}
```

but I want to perform this with simple_query_string.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible to achieve with `simple_query_string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Val's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593030/simple-query-string-check-if-field-exists#comment101644140_57593030) the syntax of the `simple_query_string` query type is limited and won't meet your requirement. If you can use the `query_string` query type, I think this will work for you:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "message:(A OR B) OR (-message:*)"
    }
  }
}
```